# Multi-line for loop in JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm totally new to JSX and am having a difficult time trying to figure out how to write multiple lines of JSX (a for-in loop in this case). Does the entire  need to be wrapped in the arrow function?

The error I see from Babeljs.io is:

```
/repl.jsx: Unexpected token (37:5)

  35 |
  36 |   return (
> 37 |     {( () => {
     |      ^

import ExpenseItem from "./components/ExpenseItem";

function App() {
  const expenses = [
    {
      id: "e1",
      title: "Toilet Paper",
      amount: 94.12,
      date: new Date(2020, 7, 14),
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      {( () => {
        for (expense in expenses) {
          <ExpenseItem
            title={expense.title},
            amount={expense.amount},
            date={expense.date}
          ></ExpenseItem>;
        }
      })()}      
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `expenses.map` e.g.

```
    <div>
      { 
        expenses.map((expense) => (
          <ExpenseItem
            title={expense.title}
            amount={expense.amount}
            date={expense.date}
          ></ExpenseItem>
        ))
      }      
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I also had to remove the commas in <ExpenseItem>. Is it not possible to write something the way I originally tried??

Comment: I've never seen it done like the way you did it originally, so I'd probably say it's not possible... but someone else may provide more insight.